# Should the tags tag and the tagging tag on meta be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

Should [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) be merged? They seem to be about the same thing.

Comment: Yes. Any consensus as to what the canonical one should be?

Comment: @JohnConde IMO [tag:tags], it's shorter.

Comment: I have performed this tag merge.

Answer (score 1):

Those tags mean the same thing and should be merged.   "tags" is shorter, so it should be the canonical.